# Want to know where am i going wrong in rotating the array by 2 position (size=n=7,distance=d=2)

Tags: c

I was trying to write a code to rotate an array by a position of 2 and I tried some logic but it is not rotating it at all.

I have tried writing a function and write my logic over there

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void rotate_arr(int arr[],int d,int n){

    int temp_new = arr[0,1];
    int i,temp;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr[0,1] = arr[d,d+1];
        temp = arr[d+1];
    }


    int last;
     for(last = 0;last<n;last++){
         arr[last]++;
         return;
     }

      arr[last] = temp_new ;
}



void main(){

    int arr[] = {2,3,4,5,6,7};

    int n = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));

    rotate_arr(arr,2,n);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d-> ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}
```

Input is {2,3,4,5,6,7}.
I  expect {4,5,6,7,2,3}.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What do you think code like `arr[0, 1]` is doing? Also `void main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: But first of all I recommend that you get a couple of beginners book about C and start reading.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
arr[0,1]
```

is not doing what you think it does (retrieving two elements).
Also, in C one variable can only ever store one value, not two.

Your code is accessing only one element in the one-dimenensional array, the second one (at index 1). It uses the result of the comma operator `,`, which in this case is 1.

For storing two values, from position 0 and 1 of an array, use two variables.

```
X=arr[0];
Y=arr[1];
```

Comment: what should i do to store the position of 1 and 2 element of an array to an temporary variabel temp Yunnosch

Comment: You cannot. Use two variables to store the two element values.

Comment: @Coder_junkyarad Looks like my answer did not help you. Is anything still unclear?